# Как сохранить Memo->Lines->SaveToFile();

Tags: c++builder

Как сохранить  несколько Memo в файл txt

когда записываем несколько Memo, оно добавляет информацию только с последнего Memo
`Memo1->Lines->SaveToFile("D:\\LID.txt");
Memo2->Lines->SaveToFile("D:\\LID.txt");
Memo3->Lines->SaveToFile("D:\\LID.txt");`

Comment: Попробуй в буффер поместить а потом уже добавить

Answer (score 1):

Lines->SaveToFile заменяет содержимое файла.

Для его сохранения можно прочитать текущее содержимое в дополнительный TStringList, добавить ещё строки методом AddStrings, затем сохранить TStringList.

В современных версиях RAD Studio для дозаписи в файл можно использовать IOUtils [AppendAllText](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE/en/IOUtils.TFile.AppendAllText)

Answer (score 0):

```
TStringList all = new TStringList();
all->AddStrings(Memo1->Lines);
all->AddStrings(Memo2->Lines);
all->AddStrings(Memo3->Lines);
all->SaveToFile("D:\\LID.txt");
delete all;
```